# Dimension of kernel and image confusion linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have a text that says (paraphrased)

> Reduce $\partial_n$ to diagonal form. Now we can read of the dimension of its image as the number of non-zero diagonal terms and the dimension of its kernel as the number of zero columns.

(It maybe relevant that $\partial_n$ is a map in a chain complex of vector spaces.)

The literal text is

[image]

This confuses me. The way I would do it is by noting that the image of a map is generated by its linearly independent columns which means that the dimension of its kernel is the number of zero columns by rank-nullity, but why is the image the number of non-zero diagonal terms?

Also, in the example, isn't the kernel of $\partial_1$ 1-dimensional? Seems to me it is generated by $(0, 0, 1)^T$.

Edit: is the example even correct? The 2-simplex is contractible so its first homology group is trivial so 0-dimensional.

Comment: I think there are some sign mistakes in the text you are reading.

Comment: Ok, I will help a bit to clear your confusion. The rank of a matrix is, as you note, the dimension of the image. So it is the maximum number of column vectors of the matrix which are linearly independent. As I wrote, there are some sign mistakes in the text you are reading. Indeed, the matrix you wrote for $\partial_1$ is invertible, so its kernel is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @Malkoun How is its kernel trivial? $(0, 0, 1)^T$ gets send to zero. Or do you mean that the row reduction is faulty?

Comment: No, it gets map to the third column. There are many mistakes in the text you are reading by the way. Oh, I see. I am looking at the original matrix on the left, not the one on the right, which is supposedly obtained by doing row/column operations (though it is incorrect).

Comment: Also, for a $2$-simplex, as you note, there is a cycle, but it bounds a face, so it is homologous to $0$. In other words, the first homology of a $2$-simplex is trivial. Hmm. Maybe try to look for another source? Have a look at Allen Hatcher's topology book for instance. Some version of it used to be free in the past. I don't know if it still is.

Comment: @Malkoun Okay, well thanks. At least I am not crazy

Comment: There should have been some signs, assuming it is standard homology theory. For instance, the boundary of the oriented segment from $1$ to $2$ should be $[2]-[1]$, and so on.

Comment: If you consider the $1$-complex which is obtained from this example by removing the $2$-dimensional face, then you essentially get a circle, and the obvious cycle will not bound a $2$-face in that case. Then you will get a rank $1$ first homology group. Maybe this is what the author meant to give as example.